# How to use count in php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count, autonumber

I want to insert data to database. I have a table, named member that has 7 column (ID, User, Password, Address, Phone, Gender, Email). I used count to make auto number like this

```
$no = "SELECT COUNT(ID)FROM member";
$nors = mysql_query($no);
$nors = $nors + 1;
$query = "INSERT INTO member VALUES (".$nors.",'".$user."','".md5($pass)."','".$name."','".$addr."',".$hp.",'".$gender."','".$email."')";
```

Why, the result of nors is 6 not 2, although I only have 1 data?

Comment: `$nors = mysql_query($no);`
this doesn't return the actual count number of your query

Comment: You might want to use something else besides md5 for storing your user passwords.  Its very insecure.  Also your code is vulnerable to SQL injections

Comment: If you're using this to generate the next ID number for a new member, you should look at making ID an auto_increment field instead - as it stands, it's possible that you'll get two members signing up at the same time, and both getting assigned the same ID.

Comment: @andrewsi Add that as an answer. I totally missed that and it's hugely important.

Comment: @CountMurphy yup, I know that md5 is insecure. I'm noob in php so I just make localhost to practice before real hosting :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mysql_query` returns a result object, not the value. Your query also lacks a needed space between `COUNT(ID)` and `FROM`...

```
$no = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS count FROM member";
$result = mysql_query($no);
$row = mysql_fetch_object($result);
$nors = $row->count;
```

You should consider using something more modern like PDO, though, as `mysql_*` functions have been deprecated and will eventually go away entirely.

**edit:** @andrewsi noted in the comments that you really should be using MySQL's built-in auto increment functionality for IDs, anyways. Much better than what you're currently doing.

Comment: Also it's recommended for id to be a primary key and insert like this: `"INSERT INTO member(User, Password, Address, Phone, Gender, Email) VALUES ('".$user."','".md5($pass)."','".$name."','".$addr."',".$hp.",'".$gender."','".$email"')"`

Comment: I've just learned php from yesterday, sorry if my code went to simple or old.. I'm trying to build up my mind. What should I do with nors then when I want to make autonumber? Should I $nors +=1; under $nors = $row->count; or just put $nors into insert?

Comment: Don't generate `$nors` yourself. Let MySQL do it for you. No code needed, and it solves many problems your current approach. See @andrewsi's answer.

Comment: **as mysql_* functions have been deprecated** where did you learn this?

Comment: @ceejayoz what should I write then in insert? $query = "INSERT INTO member VALUES ("'".$user."','".md5($pass)."','".$nama."','".$alamat."',".$hp.",'".$gender."','".$email."')" like that?

Comment: @greenthunder use my comment (the first comment here).

Comment: @AhmedJolani ID is the primary key and auto increment. I used both your code and ceejayoz. But why in my database after ID 1, it's jump into 7 not 2?

Comment: @ceejayoz I'm seconding Lawrence's comment here. The mysql_* functions HAVE NOT been deprecated. It has been discussed, and certain functions (i.e. `mysql_db_query`) have been deprecated, but the extension remains supported.

Comment: @BenD really mysql_query deprecated? what best I use then?

Comment: Thanks all, it works. the number jump into 7, because I deleted previous data so it continue numbering from the last deleted ID

Comment: @greenthunder no, mysql_query is NOT deprecated (ceejayoz suggested that is was). However, it's not considered best practice. mysqli and PDO are generally preferred.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using this to generate the next ID number for a new member, you should look at making ID an auto_increment field instead - as it stands, it's possible that you'll get two members signing up at the same time, and both getting assigned the same ID

Comment: yes, I'm using autoincrement for ID. But I don't know how to use it anyway :(

Comment: @greenthunder Just don't insert anything for Id.  The DB will do it for you.  Very easy

Comment: your id row in database should look like: id INT(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment

Comment: @CountMurphy oooh I understand now. So I don't have to write ID again in insert query. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Replace this line

```
$nors = mysql_query($no);
```

By these lines :

```
$result_handler = mysql_query($no); 
$result = mysql_fetch_array($result_handler);
$nors = $result[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

If your id field is set to be an auto number you don't need to insert it.  MySql will handle that for you.  Anytime you add a new row the autonumber is incremented. If you delete a row the autonumber does not decrement.

If you currently only have 1 row but you've added and deleted rows then your insert will produce a row with an ID that is not consecutive.